# How can I get the random slope coefficients from the statsmodels mixed effects model in python?

Tags: python, model, statsmodels, effects, mixed

I have the main summary output for my mixed effects model (using statsmodels: smf.mixedlm) and have all the beta coefficients in the summary but I would like to get all the coefficients for the each of the random slope variables I specified, to plot them. How do I do that?